# Holy javascript options in rails! Help!

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, architecture

There are a lot of different ways to use javascript in rails 3.0. I was wondering what would be the best approach for a very complex ajax application.

It seems that the more progressive programmers are using coffee script these days, and I don't mind learning something a little new.

I have already removed prototype and swapped it for jquery-rails.

Still, I'm not sure if this is enough. I reallyed like require-js, because it really helps modularize code and split everything up into different files. But does this work well with rails' approach?

Also, I may want to use a javascript application framework like backbone. Again, is this overkill or will everything work?

What is the best stack to make very complex ajax applications in rails 3.0.7? What is easiest to develop with and is a nice fit for how rails works?

These decisions are pretty important to make early on, and I don't want to be re-doing my javascript over and over until I get it right. I'd like to draw on the experience of those who've built really complex ajax apps using rails. Thanks!

Comment: Honestly, I jquery-rails contains stuff I'd probably want to customize, so I'd rather start with just jQuery. ThHe reason being because jQuery behaves like "regular javascript", except you write less code yourself to do the same thing (although you have more code on the page by including the library). jQuery-rails is a set of rules for one to follow. I'd rather make my own.

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of what I am asking - should i not use jquery-rails then? I know this will cause some things to stop working, like the scaffolded destroy links and so on, but I can always work with those too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how godly you are at not writing organically growing spaghetti code with your jQuery code everywhere.

An alternative approach is to keep your JavaScript completely separate from your rails.

You just need one entry point in a view somewhere

`script(type="text/javascript" src="require/require.js" data-main="main.js")`

I personally recommend you treat `main.js` as a boot-strapper.

Now you can do all your JavaScript through your main javascript library including loading anything you care about.

ender, Backbone, underscore, extJS (for the UI), whatever you want.

This does mean you JavaScript is very separate from your rails server, but that's ok because you do all your communication over ajax using well defined web APIS.

If your complex ajax application needs to be real time you might want to look at comet or websockets.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're overthinking it.  Rails 3 + jQuery + jQuery UI has served me just fine for complex Ajax apps.

Edit: Asset expansions allow you to group related JavaScript or stylesheet files so you can easily include them in your views.

For example, say you add this to your config/application.rb:

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # JavaScript files you want as :defaults (application.js is always included).
    config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(
      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js
      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js
      rails)

    config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:multiselect] = %w(
      jquery-tmpl/jquery.tmpl.min
      jquery-blockui/jquery.blockUI
      jquery-localisation/jquery.localisation.min
      jquery-multiselect/js/ui.multiselect)
```

In your view you might then say:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :multiselect %>
```

You can do the same with stylesheets.  The view helper for that is `stylesheet_link_tag`.  The config method is `stylesheet_expansions`.

Also look at the `content_for` helper if you want to put these in a certain place in your layout.

Comment: Asset expansions have always worked for me without too much trouble.

Comment: Using just jQuery leads to spaghetti code on any large project.

Comment: "Any" large project?  I certainly haven't had that experience.  If you're getting spaghetti code on every large project using jQuery then you should employ some code standards or consider the quality of the project developers.

Comment: jQuery is a DOM manipulation library, you need a client-side code code structuring library to manage JavaScript projects. You'll need more tools then just jQuery to write maintainable code. It's possible you've made home-grown libraries to manage this issue.

Comment: Having done full RIA apps with various JavaScript and Java frameworks, I now lean the other direction: you can achieve impressively rich interaction simply with tools and plugins built on jQuery, interacting with Rails.

Comment: Was thinking the same thin Matt

Comment: You can do a lot with jQuery. The code just stops being elegant. This also depends whether you store the Model in JS at all or whether you just use JS for rendering views and UI

Comment: Raynos is saying things that I've come across. I'm not sure if the types of things I do are more complex than the things others try? For example, there are lots of times there are no HTML-only version possible unless I wrote 2 different apps essentially. I think require.js is pretty much needed. I don't know how to get around it :( Does asset expansions basically do dependency management, or will it double up on assets?